# css z-index overlapping divs

Tags: css, html

The image below is my goal. I have 4 divs all styled to circles. I would like to align them like the picture below. Is this possible with just css's z-index? I have been trying so hard to think of a solution if anyone has some insight. You can see my progress in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/v7d4s210/1/

[image: GOAL]

```
<div id="circleContainer">
    <div class="circle spin yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle spin orange"></div>
    <div class="circle spin red"></div>
    <div class="circle spin purple"></div>
</div>

.circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #circleContainer {
        width:600px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        position: relative;
        top:200px;

    }    
    .yellow{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px; 
        background:red;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 4;
        top:-100px;
    }
    .orange{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;          
        background:blue;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 3;
        left:100px
    }
    .red{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;          
        background:green;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 2;
        left: -100px;
    }
    .purple{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;          
        background:pink;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 1;
        top:100px;
    }
```

Comment: What's this all about...`.red { background: green }`??

Comment: Oh they are loong gradients in my code so i tried to shorten them up real quick.

Answer (score 5):

Not with this markup, unless [M.C. Escher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher) were to develop a web browser, as you are trying to achieve a recursive impossibility of all items half covering the previous one. That might be possible with paper, not with a linear stack of elements. An element is either on top or it's not.

The simplest viable solution would be to replicate the circle with the lowest `z-index` again with a `z-index:5` to stay on top of everything, and wrap it in a container with `overflow:hidden` to cut off the half of it that shouldn't be visible again.

Comment: yeah thats probably the best way.